# QT5 Switching between Widgets size problem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I try to switch between two different Widgets in QT5.
The first problem was that my first window was visible in the background of my second window. I solve this with a check in "autoFillBackground". Now i can switch between them, but if i resize them it only resize the Main content.

Both Widgets have a grid layout.

Resize Problem

[image]

Im new at QT5, so is there a better way to make a switching between 2 widgets without this problem?

I try it with `wMessages = new Messages();` and `hide()` but then my program crash after going back.

---

Code:

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "messages.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_btnMessages_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Messages *wMessages;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_btnMessages_clicked()
{
    wMessages = new Messages(this); 
    wMessages->show();
}
```

messages.h:

```
#ifndef MESSAGES_H
#define MESSAGES_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Messages;
}

class Messages : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Messages(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Messages();

    QString NewsGenerator();
private slots:
    void on_bBack_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Messages *ui;
};

#endif // MESSAGES_H
```

messages.cpp:

```
#include "messages.h"
#include "ui_messages.h"

Messages::Messages(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Messages)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Messages::~Messages()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Messages::on_bBack_clicked()
{
    this->close();
    QWidget *parent = this->parentWidget();
    parent->show();
}
```

---

**Edit 1** - working Main Window Button (from G.M.´s answer):

```
void MainWindow::on_btnMessages_clicked()
{
    wPlaner = new Planer();
    QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(wPlaner);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're using `QMainWindow` incorrectly.  Instead, set the content using [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Comment: @G.M. Thanks, the Main Menu button work great (edit 1), but now i have problems with the back button. If i try the same, the problem is the inheritance from QWidget instead of QMainWindow, must i change this to QMainWindow ?

Comment: What do you mean by switching? Swapping out the widget that is shown? Did you have a look at QStackedWidget?

Comment: @ypnos jea, mean that only one widget is active at the front, like an mobile app. No i try only the code above, but thanks for the tip i look this

Comment: @Solaire Use the stacked widget if you don't need any fancy animation etc., it is designed exactly for this purpose, you will avoid performance issues, glitches etc. and also have to write less code to make it work.

Comment: @ypnos ok thank you for this tip. I try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update (based on the comments):***

The best solution was to use the `QStackedWidget` to navigate between the views.

*Docu:* https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#details

---

**Example-Code for Button:**

```
// return back to first view
void MainWindow::on_btnret_clicked()
{
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
}
```